# How to perform STD Query in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

How should I perform `STD` operation when I'm working with Django?

```
SELECT STD(total_cost)              
FROM purchase;
```

tnx

Comment: styling, in general the question was already clear

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for the Standard Deviation the following should give you what you want:

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import StdDev

print(Purchase.objects.all().aggregate(StdDev('total_cost')))
```

See the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/) for more information on how aggregation works.