# Django annotate with standard deviation

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I´m trying to annotate a queryset by the Standard deviation.

I found this post [How to perform STD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184247/how-to-perform-std-query-in-django)

And read this [documentation about querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/)

I tried this:

```
from django.db.models import StdDev
ventas_producto = ventas.values("prod_codigo").annotate(uds_std=StdDev("uds"))
```

But I get the following error:

> Exception Type:   OperationalError Exception Value: no such function:
>   STDDEV_POP

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan Django´s default sqlite3

Comment: Then it's most probably your back end not supporting the function.